# How can I remove an applied git patch?

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo, where we apply many patches in test environment.

```
git apply --stat --check --ignore-whitespace /home/kent/Desktop/patches/test.patch --exclude .gitignore

git am -s --ignore-whitespace /home/kent/Desktop/patches/test.patch --exclude .gitignore --exclude .gitignore
```

If I have to remove the patch and apply a new one, at present I clone the live content and reapply all the test patches and push again.
This process is somehow cumbersome and also leads to errors at times I also miss one or two patches.

I wanted to know if there is a way to remove a patch and apply the new one

Also, to add one way is there if we commit each time to the patch and then i can use:

```
git revert <<commit id>>
```

The above does not work for me at all times.

Comment: If you're using `git diff --patch` does `git apply -R <patch>` not work?

Comment: @ash, looks like it has worked for me.Thanks

Comment: Okay, i've applied as answer and can update/elaborate later tonight.

Comment: it will be great if you could elaborate it, as I can understand more in depth of the answer as I am not that great with git

Answer (score 171, accepted):

### TL;DR

You can revert a patch with:

```
$ git apply -R <patch>
```

---

You can generate a patch either by one of the following:

This will generate a patch from a diff

```
$ git diff --patch > 0001-some-modifications.patch
```

If you want to generate a patch for just the HEAD commit:

```
$ git show --patch HEAD^ > 0001-some-modifications.patch
```

You can generate a patch for the previous *3* commits from HEAD:

```
$ git show --patch HEAD~3 > 0001-some-modifications.patch
```

You can apply the patch by:

```
$ git apply -- 0001-some-modifications.patch
```

You can revert a patch with:

```
$ git apply -R <patch>
```

When you generate a patch it is just a diff with metadata; files, line numbers adds/removes; something along the following:

```
commit 9dad147cbf16befecdef2e812c1249499bdef5ac
Author: My Name <email@example.org>
Date:   Mon Dec 21 20:46:01 2015 +0000

    Example commit message.

diff --git a/src/example.md b/src/example.md
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..ab73512
--- /dev/null
+++ b/src/example.md
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+# Example document
+
+ Hello World
```

So when you use `git apply` you're essentially applying the edits as per to the tree.

When you then run `git apply -R` git will simply do the opposite to the patch.

Comment: Using `HEAD~3` creates a patch from a single commit for me.

Comment: `HEAD~3` specifies the third previous commit referenced by HEAD. It is like an expression that resolves to a commit.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using git on Windows and it works a bit differently than on Linux. Specifically, I found that when I ran:

```
git apply -R C:\downloads\mypatch.patch
```

This perhaps was running in the wrong directory. I had to copy it to the local directory where I was applying the patch. I also got errors like:

```
error: product/build.gradle: No such file or directory
error: main/generator/generator.js: No such file or directory
```

Which are super weird because those files are in directories specified inside of my patch. The only fix I could find for these was to modify the patch by hand. I had to change the filenames to prepend `./` to the directories and filenames. So I turned this:

```
Index: build_scripts/product/build.gradle
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- build_scripts/product/build.gradle  (revision 537fbcc1ebdf65652896eaaf2a315cc44a24ba6c)
+++ build_scripts/product/build.gradle  (date 1594123740523)
@@ -304,7 +304,7 @@
       from("$repoRootDir/src/main/nodejs/utils/") {
         include "common_*.js"
       }
```

Into this:

```
Index: ./build_scripts/product/build.gradle
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- ./build_scripts/product/build.gradle    (revision 537fbcc1ebdf65652896eaaf2a315cc44a24ba6c)
+++ ./build_scripts/product/build.gradle    (date 1594123740523)
@@ -304,7 +304,7 @@
       from("$repoRootDir/src/main/nodejs/utils/") {
         include "common_*.js"
       }
```

The only change is the `./` before the 3 different `build_scripts/product/build.gradle` strings.

Also, another nice hint is that `git apply` takes a `-v` parameter that gives a little more verbosity so you can see that it's first checking to see if the patch is safe to apply before applying it.