# Reverse a patch file

Tags: patch

I need to reverse a patch file. To be more precise I would like to make all the pluses minuses and all the minuses pluses. It is not my patch, it is not my code so I don't have git history and commits. So instead of manually writing all the lines, how could I make a reverse patch file that should work and put back what was removed and remove what was put into code with that patch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove an applied git patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400885/how-can-i-remove-an-applied-git-patch)

Comment: its not, that kind of solutions dont work